# Given an string (100*((2+12)/5))/14, how would you add spaces between each operator and number?

Tags: java

For example I want to go from this string

```
(100*((2+12)/5))/14
```

to this

```
( 100 * ( ( 2 + 12 ) / 5 ) ) / 14
```

Comment: Have you tried a solution?

Comment: Personally, I would start by trying. It is a lesser known technique but it has good results.

Comment: Yes, I tried a loop to replace any "" with " " but it added a spaces between 100.

Comment: Your can loop over the characters, if two consecutive characters are both numbers, continue with the loop, otherwise insert a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as

```
"(100*((2+12)/5))/14".replaceAll("\\D", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\d+", "$0 ").trim();
```

**Explanation:**

1. `\D` specifies a non-digit character which will be replaced with the character plus space.
2. After the above replacement is done the second replacement will be applied on the returned string. In that replacement, `\d+` specifies an integer number which will be replaced with the number plus space.
3. Finally, the trailing and leading space will be removed by `trim()`.

## Demo

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "(100*((2+12)/5))/14";
        expression = expression.replaceAll("\\D", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\d+", "$0 ").trim();

        System.out.println(expression);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
( 100 * ( ( 2 + 12 ) / 5 ) ) / 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all characters, and then check if:

- if it's the last character don't do anything
- if the current index character is not a digit then add a space after it
- if the current index character is a digit but the next character isn't then add a space after it

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "(100*((2+12)/5))/14";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            sb.append(c);
            if (i < str.length() - 1)
            {
                if ((Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i + 1))) || !Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```